# Adding view below listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created listview using ListActivity
I want to add another view below that list.So how can I do that?
here are 2 files spacelist.xml  and homescreen.java using which I have created list.

```
spacelist.xml-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@+id/label"

        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>


homeScreen.java-

public class homeScreen extends ListActivity{

    String list[]={"My Ideas","Space1","Space2","All Notes","Create New Space"};
    ListView spaces;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //To display as a list
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.spacelist, R.id.label, list);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Now suppose i want to add another view below list.How should I do?

Comment: you can do this by adding footerview in listview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with that view: always visible at the bottom of the view over the list? or is it fine with you to show that view at the bottom of the list?

First option, you could use an Activity (not ListActivity) and do whatever you want in your layout.

Second option, you can set a footer for your listview or you can have a +1 item in your listview and that item would be your view. Of course you have to manage different type of view in your adapter so it's better to set a footer.

Comment: If confirmed, please remember to accept answers and vote for helpful comments ;)